# Finding probability of a state in a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a 13 x 13 Markov chain, and I was trying to find the probability that given an initial state matrix, state 13 would occur after n iterations, and state 1 would not occur during the n iterations. How would I go about solving this problem? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems similar to another equally broad Question you asked recently.  A key request for clarification there was whether you want the designated state to occur precisely at the  $n$th step and not previously.  Are we to assume the initial state is 1? If you need help with typesetting the matrix notation, give it a try and we can help with polishing things up.

Comment: @Researcher_005: "initial state matrix" should probably be "initial state vector".

Answer (score 2):

Before we begin, recall that a state $i$ is called *absorbing* if there are no outgoing transitions from the state.
For example, the states on the far left and far right hand side of the following Markov chain are absorbing:

[image]

---

As for your problem, start by modifying the original transition matrix by turning state $1$ into an absorbing state.
Let $X$ be your original Markov chain and $Y$ be the Markov chain constructed from the modified transition matrix.
Then,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\neq1,\ldots,X_{n-1}\neq1,X_{n}=13)=\mathbb{P}(Y_{n}=13).
$$

Comment: why is P(Y_n=13) not P(X_n=13 | X_1<>1, ..., X_{n-1}<>1)?

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner: $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=13\mid X_{1}\neq1,\ldots,X_{n-1}\neq1)$ measures,
of the paths that do not intersect the first state, paths that end in the last (13th)
state. By looking at $\mathbb{P}(Y_{n}=13)$, we are not excluding
paths that intersect the first state.